# Get list of Purchased Product IDs for Restoring In-App Purchase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm creating an Application in Swift with a list of in-app purchase. What I'm trying to do is to obtain/retrieve a list of "Already Purchased" Product Identifiers.

```
func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {

}
```

For Example, in the above method we can get a list of available products. Instead of getting that list, I want to obtain the list of Already Purchased Product IDs. Then I would loop through that list and enable all the features for those products.

Is there any way to obtain that list? Or some other ways you would get that list?

Answer (score 1):

Too little information in your question and about your code. I suggest you check my question which I answered a while ago: [My IAP isn't working. Bugs at func Paymentqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741619/my-iap-isnt-working-bugs-at-func-paymentqueue)

It contains working IAP code and a few tips. I hope that helps you !

Here is the full IAP code :

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit


class GameViewController: UIViewController, ADBannerViewDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate,GADBannerViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet var outRemoveAds: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var outRestorePurchases: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("val") != nil {
            print("Has a value.")
            banner.removeFromSuperview()
            bannerGoogle.removeFromSuperview()
            outRemoveAds.removeFromSuperview()
            outRestorePurchases.removeFromSuperview()
            removeInterFrom = 1
        }
        else {
            print("No Value.")
        }

        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()){
            print("IAP is enabled, loading...")
            let productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects:"IAP id")
            let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        }
        else{
            print("Please enable IAPS")

        }

    }


    //IAP Ads

    @IBAction func removeAds(sender: UIButton) {
        for product in list{
            let prodID = product.productIdentifier
            if (prodID == "IAP id"){
                p = product
                buyProduct()
                break
            }
        }
    }
    @IBAction func restorePurchases(sender: UIButton) {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }


    //IAP Functions

    var list = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()

    func removeAds(){
        banner.removeFromSuperview()
        bannerGoogle.removeFromSuperview()
        outRemoveAds.removeFromSuperview()
        outRestorePurchases.removeFromSuperview()
        let theValue = 10
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(theValue, forKey: "val")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    }

    func buyProduct(){
        print("Buy: "+p.productIdentifier)
        let pay = SKPayment (product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
    }

    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("Product Request")
        let myProduct = response.products

        for product in myProduct{
            print("Product Added")
            print(product.productIdentifier)
            print(product.localizedTitle)
            print(product.localizedDescription)
            print(product.price)

            list.append(product as SKProduct)
        }
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("Add Payment")

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions{
            let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            print(trans.error)
            switch trans.transactionState{
            case .Purchased:
                print("IAP unlocked")
                print(p.productIdentifier)

                let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
                switch prodID{
                case "IAP id":
                    print("Remove Ads")
                    removeAds()
                default:
                    print("IAP not setup")
                }
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            case .Failed:
                print ("Buy error")
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            default:
                print("default: Error")
                break
            }
        }
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        print("Purchases Restored")

        _ = []
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as SKPaymentTransaction

            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID{
            case "IAP id":
                print("Remove Ads")
                removeAds()
            default:
                print("IAP not setup")
            }


        }
    }
    func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction){
        print("Finshed Transaction")
    }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("Remove Transaction")
    }
}
```

Put:

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
```

In `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`.